# What is "Configurable clipping rectangles"?

Tags: fpga, imageprocessing, soc

I was going through the features of one Graphics accelerator-IP core. And one important feature of this graphics accelerator is "configurable clipping rectangle". Can any one help me to under stand what is this ?

Answer (score 1):

Ignacio's answer is technically correct, but I suspect it doesn't help you much.

If you think about drawing a 3D landscape, it should be pretty clear that you don't need to draw the entire world. All you need to draw is the portion which will be displayed. And the area which needs to be drawn is typically a rectangle - most obviously the edges of the monitor which will show the final image. So a clipping rectangle is just the description of the edges of the displayed scene. The rest of the scene, outside the borders of the rectangle, are "clipped" and no processor time is wasted working on that area. In the case of your accelerator, the exact parameters of the rectangle can be set in software, and so are "configurable".

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics) for more details.

Comment: I don't think this is about 3D, it is about all graphic programming, for animation, almost 90% of the time, only a small fraction of the display is dynamic, the rest is static. In the old days designers used to use different layers of images to do so, but in a digital world, you have to use a specified rectangle to perform your dynamic operations on.

Comment: It doesn't need to be about 3D, of course, but that's the easiest (for me) way to get the basic concept. Any time you have a graphics window which shows a restricted subset of an image, and don't want to waste processor time on dealing with what's outside the window, clipping is used.